# How to create a matrix as a function of a variable

Tags: matrix, code-review, code-request

My purpose is to vary selected values in a given matrix `m0`. Below, I seek to change values in selected rows and columns using a variable denoted by `s0`.

```
ClearAll[m0,m1,rowColumn];
SetAttributes[rowColumn, HoldFirst];

Manipulate[
SeedRandom[1];
rowColumn[m_?MatrixQ, p_?VectorQ] := ( m[[p, All]] = (1 + s0); 
  m[[All, p]] = (1 + s0); m)
m0 = RandomInteger[{0, 3}, {10, 10}];  (*original matrix*)
m1 = ConstantArray[1, {10, 10}];   (*instrumental matrix*)
index={1,5,10};
rowColumn[m1, index];
(m0*m1) // MatrixForm,
{{s0,0.3},-1,1,0.1}
]
```

The above `code` works as expected, however, it looks cluttered and too much of a code just to represent matrix `m0` as a function of `s0`, namely `m0[s0]`. `index` is an arbitrary vector of the row and column numbers for inserting the variable `s0`.

I would like to reduce the `code` to a simpler form to obtain `m0[s0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  (1) make `rowColumn` a three-argument function,  (2) move definitions outside `Manipulate` or make initial definitions using the option `Initialization`, and (3) use the option `TrackedSymbols` to prevent constant updating of manipulate content.

```
ClearAll[m0, m1, index, rowColumn2];
SetAttributes[rowColumn2, HoldFirst];
rowColumn2[m_?MatrixQ, p_?VectorQ, s0_] := (m[[p, All]] = m[[All, p]] = (1 + s0); m);

SeedRandom[1]
m0 = RandomInteger[{0, 3}, {10, 10}];
m1 = ConstantArray[1, {10, 10}];
index = {1, 5, 10};

Manipulate[MatrixForm[ m0 rowColumn2[m1, index, s0]], 
  {{s0, 0.3}, -1, 1, 0.1},
  TrackedSymbols :> {s0}]
```

[image]

Comment: What OP wants is to change 1,5,10 rows and columns to `1+s0`. your function `rowColumn2` does not do this?

Comment: Thank you @OkkesDulgerci. Will fix in a moment.